# Was Prince Bertie actually known to do this?

Tags: character, historical-accuracy, victoria

I'm rewatching the British historical series, [*Victoria*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_(British_TV_series)) about the life of Queen Victoria.

During the third season we jump ahead in time to a point where Victoria already has sever children, including her eldest Princess Vicky and Prince Bertie, the latter whom may one day become King.

Bertie often feels alienated throughout the season, as he struggles to learn things such as basic arithmetic. It doesn't help that his Aunt Theodora has come to interject herself in Victoria's life, that the Royal Family has come under attacks thanks to other European revolutions and uprisings, being physically abused by one of his teachers, and a frustrated Prince Albert is continuously pressuring his son into academic success that his sister Vicky already possesses, as she is never berated for lording it over him.

At any rate Bertie finds a mouse at the Palace and is constantly carrying it around with him in last part of the season until he looses it at the end of episode 3.08.

*I was wondering if this was at all true? If Prince Bertie actually would find mice in the Palace and befriend them or if this is a fictional conceit to play on Bertie's alienation, paralleling Victoria's own disposition?*

After all in an earlier season, when gas lamps where installed, the Palace became infested with "rats" in the walls being disturbed. Rats are something Victoria fears and others used against her to contest her sanity. The Bell Boy, Archibald Brodie also was able to catch and hold the rats too in similar fashion to Bertie and his mouse.